# How to Solve Opencart add to cart issue for non product item?

Tags: php, opencart

here i have some services in my opencart store. besides the product, any one can order the services also. then we will provide the services to them. so i need add to cart option in my service page also. Services are not product, these are different item. But when i click add to cart in service item, it is not adding in cart. showing a notice

> "Notice: Undefined index: product_id in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\swifttech\system\library\cart.php on line 25".

i **modified** two files, one in **"controller/checkout/cart.php"** another **"system/library/cart.php"**. **I tried to add my code but couldn't to add here.**

Comment: @Nikhil Thank You. I am new here, your cooperation will enrich me to develop myself.

Comment: Why not make this a category and assign the services page to this category? That way you have full functionality of the cart without changing the core code within opencart

Comment: @Sphinx Thanks for your response. Yes I also thought like you, but it is client's requirement, because the services don't have attribute like products.

Comment: Well if you don't add attributes to the product it won't show up, the other alternative is to set the services to a specific category and within the controller use an if statement (`if ($category_id==0)`) which will show a differently formatted page. Then in the view you will have to differentiate between the normal products and this specific category by use of a flag

Comment: you need to make the services into products.  anything other than that is not an approach i would recommend and will break a zillion things in both store front end and admin.